# JSON String considering without Quotes values valid in Spring boot ,Java 8

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, bean-validation

I am validating a json string to bean transformation with javax annotations, I am using javax.validation.Validator interface for same, In Class, I have marked a property as String

```
@NotBlank(message ="User name cannot be null")
private String userName;
```

I expect the value coming to be in double quotes. Like {"userName" : "my name"}.

But, issue arises if I pass value as {"userName" : 1234567889} , the validator considers this as a valid value. Is there a way to restrict all such values, Or is there a list of what all cases are considered as bad Json and what are not. Any reference will be helpful.

Edit 1: May be a lot of explanation has created confusion, let me put this simple ,I want value to be accepted only when it is in double quotes, like {"key" : "value" } else constraint violated.

Comment: Is `"1234567889"` not a valid name? I agree that it would be cleaner if the value would be rejected if it is not actually a `String` but is there actually a problem with the current value being accepted?

Comment: Had this been 0123456789, it would have been rejected as JsonParseException. Problem is that I could not find all such rules whose violation which will result in JsonParseException. Thanks @luk2302 for responding.

Comment: Ah, so javax says "that is fine" but then actually parsing / transforming the data causes an exception?

Comment: check https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/bean-validation001.htm you can add validation using @Pattern with String only expression

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@Pattern(regexp="<your regular expression>",message="<message>")
```

annotation which is from **javax.validation.constraints**

Example,

```
@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z]{4,10}",message="Invalid username")
private String userName;
```

above will accept username with 4 to 10 characters

Comment: Thanks @Sam for response, I am more interested in in blocking a String Property from accepting non-quoted values.

Comment: @VatsalyaSaxena - from non quoted values you mean numbers/boolean right? but do you have requirements like your username can contain numbers or it can be a number in string format?

Comment: It can be anything , I can validate it later, it must be inside quotes